# Can I get access to a youtube player's playback state without embedding the video?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Using youtube's api, is it possible to detect whether there is an existing youtube video on any page and if so, have access to the playback state of the video?

I looked through youtube's API documentation however it seems I can only have access to the video if I embed it myself. But this needs to work on any youtube page I visit.